# Flutter - How to find username and password resource ID for Google Play Console App Access?

Tags: flutter, dart, credentials, google-play-console

On the last version of my Flutter mobile application, Google Play Console requires App Access credentials(Action Required: Provide instructions for app access), because the app is written in Dart, I don't know how to find the resource id of the username textfield and password textfield. Thanks.

[image: Provide test account credentials]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this works, but you can try to set up a key for your username and password widgets, something like:

```
TextFormField(
   key: const Key('username'),
   decoration: InputDecoration(
      labelText: 'Username',
      errorText: 'Field required',
   onChanged: (newValue) {...},
   validator: (value) {...}
),
TextFormField(
   key: const Key('password'),
   ...
)
```